# pandas iterating through each row

Tags: python, pandas

There have been no questions which addressed this specific point:

I want to iterate through the rows of a dataframe.  Specifically, within each row, I would like to call by column name.  Is there a way to do this? If so, please demonstrate.

I am familiar with the `df[<column_name>][<index_name>]`, but I don't think this addresses things. Perhaps I can mix this with the transpose function, but then I lose track of datatypes, right?

For example, if we have

```
    a b c d
 i1 1 1 2 1
 i2 2 2 1 1
```

I want to be able to say:

```
for f in some_iterator():
    print 'a is ' str(f['a'])
    print f['b'] + f['c']
    #skip f['d']
```

But as it stands, I can't depend on the column names, in this case, "a,b,c,d" to do this.

Comment: What do you mean "call by column name"?  Does [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) not do what you want?

Comment: it doesn't. it seems to spit things out in a tabular format.

Comment: As opposed to what?  DataFrames are inherently tabular.  Please clarify what you actually want to do.

Comment: hope that clears things up? thanks @BrenBarn

Comment: `iterrows` does do that, you just have to use the second element of each tuple that it yields.  (And you need to do `f['a']`, not `f[a]`.  There's no way that `f[a]` can work.)

Comment: @BrenBarn that's not true, the rows are in iterrows() are tuples, so we cannot select by column name.  So this question is still not answered.

Comment: The rows are tuples of `(index, Series)`.  You can still select by column name on the Series portion of that tuple.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn this works, though the syntax isn't as lovely as most of pandas. I'll put an answer in.

Answer (score 1):

Let `df` be a *pandas.DataFrame* object.

We can iterate through the rows by:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print str(row[0]) + " is the index of the row"
    print str(row[1]) + " is a series with rows having \
    labels the same as the columns of the dataframe"
```

Comment: Note that you can also do `for index, row in df.iterrows()` and get the index and row separately without having to access them by index.